# Sitewide htaccess url pattern match redirection

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm moving a site from one platform to another and need to use a pattern match to sitewide redirect urls on the new platform.

Old urls look like this:

```
domain.com/really-super-neat-small-red-widget.hwp
domain.com/really-super-neat-big-red-widget.hwp
domain.com/really-super-neat-very-small-red-widget.hwp
```

And they will need to be redirected to urls like this:

```
domain.com/super/small-red-widget.html
domain.com/super/big-red-widget.html
domain.com/super/very-small-red-widget.html
```

so the pattern match on the old urls will be "really-super-neat-" "term" .dwf extension

and "really-super neat" should be the "super" path in the new url followed by the term and an .html extension.

Any ideas?

Comment: You tried anything yourself? What you suppose us to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use right regex for matching your desired part from old URL.

You can use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteRule ^really-(super)-neat-(.+?)\.hwp$ /$1/$2.html [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava.  Had to modify your rule slightly, but it seemed to do the trick.  I appreciate the point in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you.